# Was a duel between representatives of the fighting armies an accepted way to end armed conflicts in ancient time?

Tags: history, war, bible, religious-texts

The bible describes the battle between Goliath and David as a dual between two champions each represents his side fighting between them selves to determine the outcome of a battle. The same is described at the [opening scene of the movie Troy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sq-uMIZGETs&feature=fvwrel)

Was it a real practice in ancient times (say before the Roman Empire)?

Comment: There are hundreds of accounts of this, though it didn't happen universally across all cultures prior to a certain time. See the wikipedia page for [single combat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_combat), specifically the "middle ages" section. "Sometimes however, such single combat would merely initiate a battle rather than prevent it." What exactly are you skeptical of here?

Comment: The movie in this followed Homer which is supposedly a historical account (historians by now treat it as such, though of course mixed with myth and legend over the centuries).

Comment: @jozzas, wasn't aware of this, when I tried to find it before asking, I didn't know it's called single combat. Put an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Hmm, I don't fancy the US's chances against Russia at the moment. How about internally: With sufficient training, a televised Romney vs Obama in a ring could potentially *make* millions instead of *costing* millions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.**

There are [hundreds of historical accounts of this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_combat), though it obviously didn't happen universally across all cultures prior to a certain time. Some cultures used single combat to resolve disputes in place of a battle, but others used the single combat as a starting point:

> "Sometimes however, such single combat would merely initiate a battle rather than prevent it."

Sword, and later, pistol duelling was a natural evolution of this activity off the battlefield.

Comment: I think sword and pistol dueling were more commonly in response to personal affronts. This paper http://www3.amherst.edu/~cgkingston/duels.pdf argues that "under certain social and economic conditions, individuals must fight in order to maintain their *personal* credit and social standing." (*Emphasis* added)

Comment: @LarryOBrien I agree. From the wiki: "the tradition of single combat was continued **away from the battlefield**, with the pas d'armes and the early modern duel." I've clarified this in my answer.